# Get which button is clicked at server when u submit via onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I have a form with two submit buttons, I am validating the form with `jquery validate` and submitting it. I want to know at server which button was clicked.

### Form

```
<form class="dp-blog-form" action="{% url 'price_assessment_section_1' component.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.as_p }}

 <!-- FORM SUBMIT BUTTONS-->

 <button type="submit" >&nbsp;Save&Home</button>

 <button type="submit" >&nbsp;Save&Next</button>

</form> <!-- end form-->
```

### JS

```
$('.dp-blog-form button[type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('.dp-blog-form').valid()) {
            unbindPageLeaveEvent();
            disableButton($(this));
            $('.dp-blog-form').submit();
        }
    });
```

How to get the button information at the sever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a hidden field in the form, in the line just above the submit, which will be sent along:

```
$('.dp-blog-form').append('<input type="hidden" name="theButton" value="'+ this.textContent +'"/>');
```

Comment: Works like a charm, simple and pretty.

Answer (score 3):

set value and name for button, you can access it from server.

```
<form class="dp-blog-form" action="{% url 'price_assessment_section_1' component.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.as_p }}

 <!-- FORM SUBMIT BUTTONS-->

 <button type="submit" name='action' value='save_home'>&nbsp;Save&Home</button>

 <button type="submit" name='action' value='save_next' >&nbsp;Save&Next</button>

</form> <!-- end form-->
```

Comment: This did not work, still cant access the value in Request.post. I am submitting the form via ` $('.dp-blog-form').submit();`

Comment: it work. also if you use <input type="submit" value="Submit" value='anything' name=''> it work too.

Answer (score 1):

we can add hidden field in a form:

```
<form class="dp-blog-form" action="{% url 'price_assessment_section_1' component.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

 {{ form.as_p }}

 <!-- FORM SUBMIT BUTTONS-->
 <input type="hidden" name="button_clicked" />

 <button type="submit" name='action' value='save_home'>&nbsp;Save&Home</button>

 <button type="submit" name='action' value='save_next' >&nbsp;Save&Next</button>

</form> <!-- end form-->
```

and in JS please set the value of clicked button into hidden field. then you will able to get the value of clicked button on server ...